# Objective-C: Using an NSString variable to send a message to one of a variety of objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'll use an example from JavaScript to help clarify my question. Let's assume I have the following object:

```
sports = {
   soccer: {...},
   basketball: {...},
   baseball: {...}
}
```

If at some point in my script I have a variable, sportString, that simply holds a string, I can dynamically call one of the sports objects in the following way:

```
sports[sportString];
```

This frees me from having to use a bunch of nested if statements, testing the value of the string such as:

```
if(sportString === 'soccer'){
    sports.soccer;
}else if(sportString === 'basketball){....
```

So, my question is how can I accomplish something similar to sports[sportString] in Objective-C, if sportString is an NSString object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as your sports object. Then you can do lookups like this:

```
[sports objectForKey: sportsString];
```

Comment: Thanks. Giving this one the answer since it's the first.

Answer (score 4):

The people saying you should use `NSDictionary` for general key/value storage are 100 % right. However, I think it’s useful to know that you *can* call a message specified by a string:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"foo"); // Or @selector(foo) if you know it at compile time
id value = [object performSelector:selector];
```

You can also use selectors with up to two arguments, as long as they take objects:

```
SEL selector2 = NSSelectorFromString(@"setFoo:");
[object performSelector:selector2 withObject:value];
```

It’s possible to invoke arbitrary methods using `IMP`s or casting `objc_msgSend()`, but now I’m getting way beyond the scope of your actual question. :-)

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Definitely useful to know about NSSelectorFromString and performSelector. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Your JavaScript object `sports` would typically be an `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`. 
Example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *sports = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[sports setObject:@"Foo" forKey:@"soccer"];
[sports setObject:@"Bar" forKey:@"basketball"];

NSString *sportString = @"soccer";
NSString *sportValue = [sports objectForKey:sportString];
NSLog(@"%@", sportValue); //logs "Foo"
```